# Ubuntu installation files

Tags: software-installation

Well this is a real lame question but simply, I've been wanting to install Ubuntu for a number of years now but just never came around to it.  I have a small 32bit Notebook that's as slow as a slug and very annoying to use (which I don't use online).  My PC I'm using ATM is a Windows7 64bit and I want to 'download' the Ubuntu software installation files needed but I want to manually install it.  Once downloaded on this terminal (64bit), can I move the install files onto a flash stick then install it into my slug notebook?  Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

This is done pretty often, so it's on the Ubuntu site:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting the files on the USB will not work. First format the USB so it is empty. Then, to create a bootable USB, use Unetbootin.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net

It will guide you through the process of creating the bootable USB.

Comment: @WillieSquatpump No problem; if it worked for you feel free to mark it as accepted.